# How do I in an app get the BSSID of my device's hotspot access point on android

Tags: android, android-wifi, hotspot

When I have an android device configured for and acting as a hotspot ( wifi access point) how can I get the current (possibly generated and unique for each activation of the hotspot) BSSID seen by other devices for the current active hotspot. Not the SSID but the BSSID.

Comment: did you find any solution? i'm looking exactly for the same thing right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiInfo info = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String BSSID = info.getBSSID();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this works to get the BSSID of a wifi the android phone is CONNECTED to but does not get the BSSID it publishes to others when It is being used as a personal hotspot.  That is the goal.